# How to relate between two probability distribution functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions

$f$ and $g$ are probability distribution functions (PDFs) of two random variables $X$ and $Z$, respectively. Random variables $X$ and $Z$ are related as 
$$Z= X\sqrt{n+2}$$.

With this relation, their PDFs are given as:

$$g(z) = \frac{f\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{n+2}}\right)}{\sqrt{n+2}}.$$
Is this relation of PDFs correct? How can I derive this relation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c = \sqrt{n+1}$, so that $Z = cX$. We have 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Z \leq z) &= \mathbb{P}\left(X \leq \frac{z}{c}\right)\\
\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d }z} \mathbb{P}(Z \leq z) &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d }z}\mathbb{P}\left(X \leq \frac{z}{c}\right) 
= \frac{1}{c} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d }z/c}\mathbb{P}\left(X \leq \frac{z}{c}\right)
= \frac{1}{c} \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d }x}\mathbb{P}\left(X \leq x\right)\right|_{x = z/c}\\
\Rightarrow g(z) &= \frac{1}{c} f\left(\frac{z}{c}\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Consider the CDF of Z...

$$
\begin{align*}
F_Z(z) 
&= P(Z \leq z) \\
&= P(X\sqrt{n+2} \leq z) \\
&= P\left(X \leq \frac{z}{\sqrt{n+2}}\right) \\
&= F_X\left( \frac{z}{\sqrt{n+2}}\right)
\end{align*}
$$

From here just take the derivative of both sides to obtain the PDF.